# Testing camel 2.24.x routes in Karaf 4.2.7 with CamelTestSupport

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, pax-exam, camel-test

I want to test Camel 2.24.x routes in Karaf 4.2.x. I use Pax-Exam 4.13.1 to run Karaf. The [Camel Testing Manual](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/testing.html) does not cover Karaf testing. For older Karaf and Camel versions there are blog articles which demonstrate how to do that by extending a test class from `CamelTestSupport`:

- [Testing Camel JPA routes with Pax-Exam and Karaf](https://nierbeck.de/2013/08/testing-camel-jpa-routes-with-pax-exam-and-karaf/)
- [Testing (utest and itest) Apache Camel Blueprint route](http://blog.nanthrax.net/?p=679)

However, they are so old that the code no longer runs without adjustments. The former is pretty hopeless, I have stopped trying to fix it. For the latter I was able to get it to work on [Karaf 2.4 with Camel 2.12.1 on JDK 8](https://github.com/dschulten/blog-camel-blueprint/tree/karaf24-jdk8), but not with the current [Karaf 4.2.7 using Camel 2.24.2](https://github.com/dschulten/blog-camel-blueprint/tree/karaf4-paxexam4).

With the current Karaf 4 and Camel 2.24 I get the following error message when `CamelTestSupport` tries to create a `JndiContext` in `CamelTestSupport#createRegistry`.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.util.jndi.CamelInitialContextFactory

    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.doImplicitBootDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1859)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.tryImplicitBootDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1788)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchDynamicImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1741)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1617)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:91)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.createJndiContext(CamelTestSupport.java:790)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.createRegistry(CamelTestSupport.java:776)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.createCamelContext(CamelTestSupport.java:770)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.doSetUp(CamelTestSupport.java:325)
    at org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport.setUp(CamelTestSupport.java:265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
```

The missing class is in `camel-core` and it used to be working with the older versions of Camel and Karaf, so I am at a loss why that class would not be available when using the latest Karaf and Camel.

What could be the reason why the `CamelInitialContextFactory` cannot be found? As in the older version, I [install `camel-blueprint` and `camel-test`](https://github.com/dschulten/blog-camel-blueprint/blob/e0b8c9d6f2fc83df55ef3a483734c9fa38bffb7d/itests/src/test/java/net/nanthrax/blog/itests/MyRouteTest.java#L43) in my test, so I would expect that `camel-core` should be included.

Is it still a good idea to work with `CamelTestSupport` on Karaf? While there is a [CamelKarafTestSupport](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/camel-2.24.2/components/camel-test-karaf/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/test/karaf) which seems to demonstrate that approach, I could not find a working example for such a test and I could not get it to work myself either. With `CamelKarafTestSupport` I get an error telling me that `ProbeInvoker` never came up:

```
org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookupException: gave up waiting for service org.ops4j.pax.exam.ProbeInvoker

    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookup.getService(ServiceLookup.java:199)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookup.getService(ServiceLookup.java:136)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.internal.RemoteBundleContextImpl.remoteCall(RemoteBundleContextImpl.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.remoteCall(Unknown Source)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl$1.invoke(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.rbc.client.intern.RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.call(RemoteBundleContextClientImpl.java:290)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.container.remote.RBCRemoteTarget.call(RBCRemoteTarget.java:60)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.karaf.container.internal.KarafTestContainer.call(KarafTestContainer.java:665)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.spi.reactors.EagerSingleStagedReactor.invoke(EagerSingleStagedReactor.java:109)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner$2.evaluate(ProbeRunner.java:267)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.impl.ProbeRunner.run(ProbeRunner.java:98)
    at org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam.run(PaxExam.java:93)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Should I go a different route, maybe the `AbstractFeatureTest` from `camel-test-karaf`, which is used extensively by [camel-itest-karaf](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/tests/camel-itest-karaf)?

Comment: I've now tried to install camel-core alongside camel-blueprint and also just camel instead. No change.

Comment: When I run the unpacked Karaf after the test, `bundle:list` shows that camel-core has been installed successfully.

Comment: Got an answer in the pax-exam group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ops4j/u703WtXpK20

Answer (score 0):

The advice in the pax-exam [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ops4j/u703WtXpK20) was to use `KarafTestSupport` from `org.apache.camel.itests:common` for integration tests in pax-exam and stick to `CamelTestSupport` for unit tests.
With that, I got the camel itests running again: https://github.com/dschulten/blog-camel-blueprint/tree/karaf4-paxexam4.
In Karaf 4.2.7  KarafTestSupport requires numerous spring and activemq version system properties (see the configuration of the maven-surefire-plugin), that will go away as of Karaf 4.2.8.
It is still possible to use camel mock routes in `KarafTestSupport`-based integration tests.